# Отличить jQuery от prototype

Tags: jquery, prototype, javascript

В проекте используются местами совместно jQuery и prototype, (так исторически сложилось). 
Подскажите как отличить файлы содержащие jQuery от prototype? Дабы отловить все файлы prototype и включать их только там где нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых в jquery любая выборка элементов делается вызовом `$("selector")` в prototype `$("selector")` это тоже что и `document.getElementById("selector")`.

Для выборок не по id в  prototype используеться `$$("selector")`, вот собственно.

Обработчик в prototype инициализируются следующим образом:

```
Event.observe(element, "eventName", function(e){});
// на element навешиваем обработчик события eventName, в нашем случае это анонимная функция

// либо
element.observe("eventName", function(e){}); // на элемент element - событие eventName

// либо
Event.observe("elementId", "eventName", function(e){})
```

Например для обработки события загрузки окна может использоваться конструкция вида:

```
Event.observe(window,"load",function(){});
```

---

Ну и создание классов в prototype:

```
var ClassName = Class.create({
    initialize: function(){}
    // .....
})
```

---

Ну и еще в prototype абсолютно по другому устроен ajax API, пример prototype ajax запроса:

```
new Ajax.Request("requestUrl",{
    parameters: {
         someKey: "someValue"
    },
    onSuccess: function(request) {
         // request - объект xmlHtppRequest
         // соответственно ответ сервера например храниться в request.responseText
         // пример преобразования json ответа
         var fromJson = request.responseText.toJSON(true);
    },
    onFailure: function(){}; // обработчик фейла ^^
});
```

---

Вообще довольно просто отличить jquery код и prototype код. JQuery "навязывает" использование своих функций и по сути как-бы "уходит" от нативного javascript.
Таким образом в jquery коде вы врятли увидите что-то кроме вызова jquery либо пользовательских функций.

Что касается prototype кода - в части кода используются методы prototype, в части - нативный js(ну или пользовательские методы, классы, события и т.д.)

Если возникнут еще вопросы спрашивайте.

PS: о jquery не писал т.к. обычно все, так или иначе, этот фреймворк знают

Comment: Спасибо за расширенный ответ.

А так ли, если на странице встретиться код prototype то jQuery будет не корректно работать по любому?

Comment: [тыц](http://malkin.com.ua/2008/03/how-to-make-prototype-and-jquery-to-work-together/) и будет вам счастье ;)

Comment: Этот метод знаю, так то и делал, но проект огромен, и уже порядком надоело менять $. Решил что проще будет почистить проект от prototype где он не нужен.

Comment: Не очищайте prototype :(. И так - куда не плюнь JQuery