# В чём преимущество prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

Вот есть код:

```
(function(){

var Test = function(name){

    this.name = name;
    this.talk = function(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }

};

// ИЛИ

/*Test.prototype.talk = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
}*/

var currA = new Test('Jack');
var currB = new Test('Jessy');
var currC = new Test('Ronny');


currA.talk();
currB.talk();
currC.talk();

})();
```

Зачем использовать *prototype*?

Если в внутри условного класса можно задать сразу функцию. Скажите разницу плиз, а то запутался немного в этом.

Comment: Разница в том, что если функция не найдена в исходном классе (хотя это не совсем классы), то она ищется в prototype. Теоретически, если руками рисовать каждому объекту повторяющуюся функцию, то будет создана куча объектов функций, вместо одного в prototype. Даже если JS это оптимизирует, то все равно без указателя на функцию в объекте не обойтись. Если методов 20, то это плюс 20 указателей на объект. И еще, функция, создаваемая в конструкторе, захватит с собой фрейм конструктора как замыкание, а это не нужно.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Может оформите как ответ?

Comment: Не будут лишними: [За что отвечает свойство prototype после имени класса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/519395/189339), [Отличить jQuery от prototype](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/66201/189339), и [Значения прототипов в Javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581414/189339) думаю, что стоит почитать.